# How to submit form using other controller in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers

I have a form in phtml file. There are 2 fields in that username and password. I want to set that username and password value from other controller and submit that form.

I tried using this below way :

```
$this->request->setPostValue('username','admin');
$this->request->setPostValue('password','admin@123');
```

But, Still I can't receive value in **$this->getRequest()->getPost('username');**

How can i do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried - $this->getRequest()->getParams(); ?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Can you add controller code & phtml code ?